# How to fix "The TensorFlow library was compiled to use AVX512F instructions, but these aren't available on your machine."

Tags: tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow 1.12.
The platform is:
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700K CPU @ 3.60GHz
1080Ti
Ubuntu 16.04
Anaconda python 3.5

The tensorflow itself is ok. But when I run tensorboard, I get the following error:
The TensorFlow library was compiled to use AVX512F instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.
Aborted.
How can I fix this issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You can find the solution [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24548). I will quote it as reference

> The current version of Tensorflow installed via pip uses the AVX
>   instruction set at compile time.This means that your CPU needs to
>   support the AVX instruction set. This instruction set is supported
>   from the second generation of Intel Core CPUs (codenamed SandyBridge).
>   You can compile a Tensorflow from the source that does not use the AVX
>   instruction set. Or find an already compiled one on the internet.

So you need to build it from source or use a build that was not compiled using AVX.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have compiled tensorflow from source code and installed the generated whl file successfully. The tensorflow works well. But tensorboard is still reporting the same error. When I install the generated tensorflow-XX.whl, the tensorboard is collected from the internet. I cannot control where the tensorboard is collected from. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: My cpu support avx and avx2, but not avx512f. How can I specify this when building tensorflow? or is it specified automatically? My another laptop doesnot support avx512f, but tensorflow1.12 (but with py3.6) and tensorboard work well on the laptop.

Comment: Now I compile tensorflow r1.10 and the tensorboard is OK.